# Let $X_n$ be succession of independent exponentials of parameter $\lambda$.

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

Let $X_n$ be succession of independent exponentials of parameter $\lambda$.

Let $Z_n = max(X_1,...,X_n)$

I want to study the convergence of $Z_n$ and of $\frac{1}{\log{n}}Z_n$

First of all I find the CDF of $Z_n$:
$$ F_{Z_n}(z) = (1-e^{-\lambda z})^n $$

The limit of n going to infinity is 0 but there doesn't exist a random function with CDF constant equal to 0, so It doesn't converge in law.

Now if I multiply for $\frac{1}{\log{n}}$, I get:

$$F_{\frac{1}{\log{n}}Z_n}(z) = (1- e^{-\lambda \log{n} z})^n$$

This should converge to the constant $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
P(Z_n\le z\log n) = \left(1-\frac{1}{n^{\lambda z}}\right)^n = \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{\lambda z}}\right)^{n^{\lambda z}}  \right)^{\frac{n}{n^{\lambda z}}} \\
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\lim_n P(Z_n\le z\log n)
&= \frac{1}{e}, \quad \mbox{ if } \lambda z=1\\
&= 1, \quad \mbox{ if } \lambda z>1\\
&= 0, \quad \mbox{ if } \lambda z<1
\end{align}
which means that the sequence $Z_n/\log n$ converges in distribution to $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ (we do not care about the point $z=1/\lambda$ because it is not a point of continuity of the distribution function of the constant random variable $1/\lambda$). Since it converges to a constant, $Z_n/\log n$ also converges in probability.

Comment: I don't see why it should converge to $\frac{1}{\lambda}$..

Comment: Think about the CDF of the random variable $1/\lambda$ (ie, 0 if $z<1/\lambda$ and 1 if $z\ge 1/\lambda$). Then, apply exactly the definition of convergence in distribution (eg, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution )